# Most effective way to fold polynomial parse tree

Tags: parsing, haskell, fold, parse-tree

I am working on a symbolic algebra system. I'm currently looking at how to carry out polynomial addition/multiplication from a binary parse tree. I will later consider this to be a general ring.

Parsing is *not* relevant here -- this intended to be the output of parsing. The parse tree that is formed. If something could be improved here, I'm certainly happy to learn about that too.

I 'feel' that this tree structure could be folded/crushed, yet I'm not too clear on how to go about it. I believe I can hack something together, but as I'm still learning Haskell, I wanted to learn what the more advanced users would do.

Below is relevant code background.

My two relevant data declarations are:

```
data Op = Add | Mul
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node Op [Tree a] [Tree a]
```

Here's one of my test examples:

```
-- 3*(x+2)*(x+(5*4))
test = Node Mul [
         Node Mul 
          [Leaf "3"] 
          [Node Add 
            [Leaf "x"] 
            [Leaf "2"]
          ]
         ] 
         [Node Add 
           [Leaf "x"] 
           [Node Mul 
             [Leaf "5"] 
             [Leaf "4"] 
           ]
         ]
```

This is a typical recursive tree type, with a node holding an operation as well as lists of left and right trees. Computation proceeds by the below operations. Note: they are all string operations for now. I need them to be as general as possible (but will later add further structure, like multiplicative commutativity).

```
prod :: [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]]
prod ls rs = [Leaf (l ++ r) | (Leaf l) <- ls, (Leaf r) <- rs]

add :: [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]]
add l r = l ++ r

opOnLeaf :: Op -> [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]] -> [Tree [a]]
opOnLeaf op l r  
  | op == Add = add l r
  | op == Mul = prod l r

operate :: Tree [a] -> [Tree [a]]
operate (Node op [Node op2 l2 r2] [Node op3 l3 r3]) = operate (Node op (operate (Node op2 l2 r2)) (operate (Node op3 l3 r3)))
operate (Node op [Node op2 l2 r2] r) = operate (Node op (operate (Node op2 l2 r2)) r)
operate (Node op l [Node op2 l2 r2]) = operate (Node op l (operate (Node op2 l2 r2)))
operate (Node op l r) = opOnLeaf op l r
```

I think my variable names in `operate` are hideous, but I wanted to ensure it functioned first. Making it all hideous makes it stands out more too. It's practically yelling at me to find a better way.

Now, I'd like to use fold or foldMap, but I run into the issue that I have distinct monoids at each operation (namely `(*)` and `(+)`. And that's just the beginning -- I will be adding several other operations. So I'd need something like a 'variable monoid', or perhaps some other map whose operation was to first acquire the monoid. I'm not sure.

The query: given this binary tree, and multiple operations at each node, how would one proceed to fold up the structure? Is there a better way to write this as an instance of Foldable, or some other structure? I also aim to add several other binary operations. Ideally, I'd like a structure that'd be indefinitely extensible. I assume once it's solved for 2, we could solve it effectively for n.

[Tree drawing corresponding to test example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxWg6.jpg)

Comment: Why do you use lists of the `Node` constructor, shouldn't `Node Op (Tree a) (Tree a)` make more sense?

Comment: It very well might. Here is my rationale thus far. (1) After each operation application (e.g., Add), each subtree is reduced to a list. I want to carry [Leaf] type upwards as I proceed; (2) In some cases, after parsing, I'd like to have multiple values to start with, like: [Leaf 2, Leaf 3, Leaf 4], if I want to represent 2 + 3 + 4. So as I'm working with lists of Leaf, I work with lists of Tree. I don't think this rationale is too convincing however (I am writing this ad hoc); it does make sense to not have lists of Nodes if they're always binary. Perhaps I'd need more types.

Comment: in a `foldr` on a high level you change out one operator (for example `:`) with another and all the *leaves*  with matching values. So here you would need something like `foldTree :: ([acc] -> [acc] -> Op -> acc) -> acc -> Tree a -> acc` (left-accs, right-accs, operator -> new acc) - I guess you could implement this and I'd not sure if this is helpful though

Comment: (1) So reduce it to a list -- and not a list of trees. Write `prod :: Tree a -> Tree a -> [[a]]`, etc., instead of this crazy type you have. (2) Parse that to `Node Add (Leaf 2) (Node Add (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))` instead.

Comment: If you want to associate operators with lists, then give each `Node` *one* list and not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fold" has two related but distinct meanings in common parlance.

1. `Fold` as in [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html). Viewing the datatype as a container, `Foldable` gives you access to the container's elements while *throwing away any information* about the shape of the container itself. (This is also the sense in which `lens`'s [`Fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html) uses the term.) Not every datatype is `Foldable` — only those which can be viewed as a container.
2. "Fold" can also mean "catamorphism", which is a technique for writing higher-order functions which reduce a structure to a summary value. Every datatype has a corresponding catamorphism, but the signature of the catamorphism depends on the datatype.

The two meanings of "fold" happen to coincide when the datatype you're talking about is `[]` (which partly explains the confusion over the two meanings), but in general they don't. Your `Tree` happens to be a suitable candidate for either type of fold, and from your question I can't quite tell which one you're after, so I'll show you how to do both.

---

The easiest way to write an instance of `Foldable` is to turn on `DeriveFoldable`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node Op [Tree a] [Tree a]
  deriving (Foldable)
```

But for the sake of understanding I'll write out the instance here:

```hs
instance Foldable Tree where
    -- foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
    foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
    foldr f z (Node _ ls rs) = foldr foldTree z (ls ++ rs)
        where foldTree t z' = foldr f z' t
```

The idea is to traverse the tree to the bottom, applying `f` to the values inside each `Leaf`. Couple of things to note about this code:

- `foldr` is an overloaded function (it's a method of `Foldable`), and in the second clause I'm using it at two different types. The `foldr` in `foldTree` is a recursive call to `Tree`'s definition of `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b`. The `foldr` in the line above it is a call to the usual list `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`.
- `foldr` discards information! In the `Node` case, you can see from the `_` that the `Op` is dropped on the floor. We also smash `ls` and `rs` together into a single list, forgetting that they used to be in two lists.

So `Foldable` is all about finding the items inside a container, while discarding any information about the container itself. To put it bluntly, `Foldable` is "`toList`-as-a-class".

`Foldable` is a great fit for container types and other abstract data types, where you want to expose a collection-like interface while hiding the internal representation of the data structure. In your case, you mentioned that you wanted to apply an operation `+` or `*` depending on the `Op` inside the tree, but the `Op` is *discarded* by `Foldable`. So it seems like `Foldable` is not the right tool for what you're trying to do.

---

If you want to reduce your datatype to a summary value *without* throwing away any information about the structure, you need a *catamorphism*.

To derive the signature for a catamorphism, follow this recipe.

1. `cata` takes a value of your datatype and returns a summary value `b`.
2. Each constructor of your datatype corresponds to an argument for `cata`. Each of those arguments will be a function which returns a `b`.
3. Each field of your datatypes' constructors corresponds to one of the corresponding function's arguments.
4. Recursive mentions of the datatype itself become summary values `b`.

Let's follow these steps for your `Tree`. First of all, `cataTree` takes a `Tree` and returns a summary value `b`.

```hs
cataTree :: ??? -> Tree a -> b
```

Looking at `Tree`'s definition, we see two constructors. So `cataTree` will have two function arguments, one for `Leaf` and one for `Node`.

```hs
cataTree :: ({- Leaf -} ??? -> b) -> ({- Node -} ??? -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

Looking at the `Leaf` constructor, we see one field. So the `Leaf` function has a single argument.

```hs
cataTree :: (a -> b) -> ({- Node -} ??? -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

Now let's look at `Node`. `Node` has three arguments, but two of them are lists of `Tree`s. We want to replace each of those `Tree`s with its corresponding summary value. So the final signature for `cataTree` is

```hs
cataTree :: (a -> b) -> (Op -> [b] -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

Implementing `cataTree` is a matter of following the types.

```hs
cataTree leaf _ (Leaf x) = leaf x
cataTree leaf node (Node op ls rs) =
    node op (fmap (cataTree leaf node) ls) (fmap (cataTree leaf node) rs)
```